# halló la puerta abierta: "she found the door open" or "she found the open door?

Tags: adjetivos, sintaxis, subordinadas

The Oxford Spanish Dictionary tells me that *halló la puerta abierta* means "she found the door open". Is there an omitted "to be" between *puerta* and *abierta*, as in the English "she found the door to be open"? And how would you say "she found the open door" in Spanish?

Also in the dictionary: *encontré la puerta cerrada* means "I found the door shut".

Answer (score 2):

In Spanish:

1. Halló la puerta abierta / cerrada.

is ambiguous, as it can mean:

1.a. He/She found the door open / closed (= He/She found that the door was open / closed / He/She found the door to be open/closed)

or

1.b. He/She found the open / closed door (= He/She found the door that was open / closed)

If the interpretation is 1.a., "abierta/cerrada" in sentence (1) is an object complement, that is, an attribute that refers to the direct object but does not form part of it. If the interpretation is 1.b., "abierta/cerrada" in sentence (1) modifies the head of the direct object, that is, "puerta". Unlike in interpretation 1.a., in interpretation 1.b. "abierta/cerrada" forms part of the direct object.

To disambiguate, the only possible way I can think of is to expand the structure:

1.a. Halló que la puerta estaba abierta/cerrada.

1.b. Halló la puerta que estaba abierta/cerrada.